# Enable Emacs to suggest the available methods of a class

Tags: completion, c++, ide

I have setup Emacs to work almost like an IDE but I haven't managed to make it suggest the available methods of every class.

I currently write in C++ and previously I was using Visual Studio so when I was pressing the dot it would suggest to me the available methods.

As the methods most of the times are countless this is a very important feature for me but I have yet to find how to implement it.

I believe that this is a problem of every person writing code so I can only guess that there is surely a package for Emacs to offer this functionality. Can someone suggest any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) is a complete package that is supposed to give Emacs IDE features comparable to Visual Studio or Eclipse.  It has a reputation for being fairly complicated to set up, but there are a lot of tutorials on it in both web page and YouTube form: [here's one that looks pretty easy to follow](https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/173886).

Alternatively, if all you want is auto-suggestion of member function names, I have heard [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) recommended highly.  Combined with [tags](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags#tags) and [Projectile](http://batsov.com/projectile/) you would have a much lighter-weight installation than CEDET with most of the key IDE functionality.

Comment: Your suggestion is interesting but as I read most sources say that it is outdated. It seems strange to me that a feature so common has not a more easy and up-to-date package.

Answer (score 3):

For code completion, I suggest you to use [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) along with [company-irony](https://github.com/Sarcasm/company-irony). You can easily get them from MELPA. When you finished installing, you have to build Irony server with `M-x irony-install-server`. You also have to add a `.clang_complete` file at the project root path with compile flags for including source header paths, so Irony can use that information to parse your files and provide the feature you are needing. If files are in the current directory, Irony can automatically recognize it.

My [C/C++ guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) my help you to do the following:

- Find definitions in project, even as large as Linux kernel.
- Find references in project.
- Find any file in a using Projectile using Helm and Helm Projectile, as in [this guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html), even if your project has as many files as Linux kernel or more.
- Completion system header with [company-c-headers](https://github.com/randomphrase/company-c-headers).
- Source code information for current identifier at point that look like this:

[image: semantic-idle-summary]

- Display out of screen function name at the top. This is from the package [semantic-stickyfunc-enhance](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-stickyfunc-enhance).

[image: stickyfunc-enhance]

- Small scale code refactoring with [semantic-refactor](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor). You can see all the demos [here](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor/blob/master/srefactor-demos/demos.org).

  - Context-sensitive menu offers appropriate refactoring actions
  - Generate class implementation (also handles nested class and class template)
  - Generate class getters and setters
  - Generate function implementation (also handles function template)
  - Generate function prototype
  - Convert function to function pointer
  - Convert function to function parameter
  - Move semantic units (class, function, variable)
  - Extract function with proper type information
  - Precise local variable rename

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it is focused on code completion which I have already implemented.

Comment: So, which package did you choose? `Irony` or something else?

Comment: I chose `auto-complete`. When I installed it I didn't even know that `irony` existed.